# Playfarmework testing: Upload file with Fake Request and mulipartFormData

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework-2.5

I'm trying to unit test a file upload through multipartFormData and returning status 200 if it returns back the uploaded url. However, I keep getting status 400 and unsure why its been unsucessful.

I've found online of the call needs to be writeable and have included a writeable class which i've imported as lazy val

```
"return a 200 if successful" in new SetUp {
      val fakeFileName = "testImage.png"
      val fakeUploadImageUrl = "https://s3.fakeImageUrl.png"
      val imageFile = new File(fakeFileName)
      val tempFile = TemporaryFile(imageFile)
      val multipartFormData = new MultipartFormData(
        dataParts = Map(),
        files = Seq(FilePart[TemporaryFile]("file", fakeFileName, Some("text/plain"), tempFile)),
        badParts = Seq()
      )

      when(imageService.uploadWebImage(any(), any())).thenReturn(Future.successful(fakeUploadImageUrl))

      val request = FakeRequest(HttpVerbs.POST, s"/internal/challengesv2/v1/instances/image/$fakeFileName")
        .withBody(multipartFormData)

      val response = testController.uploadImage(fakeFileName).apply(request)

      assert(status(response.run()) === 200)
      assert(contentAsJson(response.run()) === Json.toJson(fakeUploadImageUrl))
}
```

expect 200 but returning 400

Comment: finally resolved. The issue was File does not to be created but rather only TemporaryFile was needed. Also the call to testController was written to include manually include materializer which call(controller.method(), request) already includes materializer in the call method.